# Difference between ATL CAutoPtr and STL std::auto_ptr?

Tags: shared-ptr, auto-ptr, cautoptr

I'm writing some code in MFC and I want to use auto pointers. I've come across two different classes that look like they do the same thing: `CAutoPtr` and `std::auto_ptr` What are people's thoughts about the two different implementations?

Further, I know there is `std::tr1::shared_ptr`. Is there a similar `shared_ptr` that is in ATL/MFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `CAutoPtr` and `auto_ptr` give you smart pointer semantics including transfer of ownership semantics. `CAutoPtr` is an ATL class -- built using COM. It is a non-standard extension for a particular OS. `auto_ptr` on the other hand is standard C++. If you want to use a container of such objects you have to use `CAutoPtrArray` or `CAutoPtrList`.

An important point to note is that there is something called `auto_ptr_ref` that allows you to return `auto_ptr`s as a return value. There is no such thing with `CAutoPtr`.

`auto_ptr` is deprecated in C++0x. Use `unique_ptr` if you have to: you can use them in move-aware containers and also get some safety from unsafe implicit moves of l-values.

Comment: Nice answer.  However, as far as I know CAutoPtr has nothing to do with COM.

Comment: CAutoPtr is not OS or COM specific, - it's plain old C++.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to shared_ptr in ATL/MFC is CComPtr. It is meant to be used on COM objects, but it can be used on any class that includes AddRef/Release reference counting methods.

Answer (score 0):

CAutoPtr is ATL specific .

std:auto_ptr and CAutoPtr both don't provide reference counting. It looks like both have same functionality.[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139622/does-the-cautoptr-class-implement-reference-counting)

I guess there is no shared_ptr in ATL/MFC. shared_ptr is implemented in boost library.